# Как передать массив слов в конструктор и его обработать?

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, конструктор, процедуры

Добрый день.

Как передать массив слов в процедуру и затем его обработать, например, посчитать что-нибудь, т.е. нужно преобразовать указатель на массив в массив слов (или строк). Реализация интересует на С++ в классах либо в функциях.

Comment: Эта было реализовано через адресную арифметику над указателем массива строк, сработает только в том случае если известна длинна сроки в массиве, т.е. заданна явно при объявлении переменной. Вот здесь http://pastecode.ru/89549/ выполнена реализация в конструкторе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что вы имеете в виду под термином «слово»? Строка? На C++ обычно пишут так:

```
void f(const std::vector<std::string>& words)
```

И **никаких** указателей, пишите на идиоматическом C++.